# Element-UI: How to increase icon size of buttons?

Tags: element-ui

I am simply showing a button like this:

```html
<el-button plain circle icon="el-icon-refresh"></el-button>
```

But the icon inside the button is too small. Is there a way to enlarge the icon only? I am using `Vue.js` for my project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Element-ui doesn't support this by it's API. However the icon attribute places a class on i-element within a button. you are able to add a second class and add you own styling.

```
<el-button plain circle icon="custom-icon el-icon-refresh"></el-button>
```

CSS:

```
.custom-icon {
   font-size: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: what about just icons, not buttons

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

**HTML**

```
<el-button plain circle icon="el-icon-refresh" class="custom-icon"></el-button>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom-icon {
   font-size: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: This just a repeat of existed answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

HTML:

```
<el-button icon="el-icon-circle-plus-outline">Add</el-button>
```

CSS:

```
<style lang="less" scoped>
    /deep/ .el-icon-circle-plus-outline {
        font-size: 15px;
    }
</style>
```