# ELEMENT UI - How to increase the size of ICON?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, element-ui

```
 <i class="el-icon-delete col-sm-3"></i>
```

I tried so many class to increase size of icon . But nothing won't work . Help me to increase size of element UI icon

Comment: Just use `font-size`. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57951848/4125678

Answer (score 0):

the icon has same property as normal text.
just use

```
<style>
.el-icon-delete {'
  font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
```

just change the size with the size you want.